# Understanding pull requests on GitHub: What happens, when the requesting repository is deleted?

Tags: git, github, open-source, pull-request

Following scenario:

I forked an open source repository (`GitHub -> project -> Fork`). Then I cloned my project copy locally, made some changes in the master branch, commited them, and pushed to my repository:

```
$ git clone git@github.com-myusername:myusername/originalprojectname.git
... changes ...
$ cd originalprojectname
$ git add path/to/changed/file.php
$ git commit -m "..."
$ push
```

After it I started a pull request on GitHub. It has been marked as "Good to merge" and added to `Milestone: x.y.z`.

Where is the changed code staying? Only in my repo or also something else? The backgroud is: I would like to delete my repository. So, finally my question: **If I delete my repository on GitHub, are the changes still available then for the original project or should I wait for the release `x.y.z`?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, **the code will still be there after you delete your repo**. As soon as you submit your pull-request, Github internally adds that branch to the target repo (it creates a branch in a non-default namespace, so you usually don't see those).

Since PRs cannot usually be deleted, those branches will exist in the target repo indefinitely.

To answer your other question: The code will reside in both your fork and the target repo (originally, at least, unless you delete your fork).

Comment: FYI, [this talk by Zach Holman](http://zachholman.com/talk/more-git-and-github-secrets/) (GitHub employee) confirms that "GitHub stores all pull requests in your repository […] even if the fork is deleted".

Comment: when I refork the deleted repo from upstream, can I continue update the previous PR thread?