# Can I delete my fork of a BitBucket repository, after the owner has accepted and merged my pull request?

Tags: repository, bitbucket, pull-request

I created a fork of a public repository on BitBucket, with the sole purpose of committing a pull request that fixed some bug. The pull request was accepted and merged. Now, I want to delete the repository, that has outlived its purpose. If I do that, will the changes be lost?

There is already [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080544/understanding-pull-requests-on-github-what-happens-when-the-requesting-reposit) about this same issue, but for GitHub. Apparently, on GitHub you can delete the repository before the request has been even merged, as it gets automatically saved in the target repository. I guess that on BitBucket, things will be similar, but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say if things work as expected on GitHub, then they would work on BitBucket.  If the pull request was "accepted and merged", then nothing you do to your personal repository will modify the repository that has merged in your changes.

Comment: You were both right, nothing happened. I can't upvote you due to lack of reputation, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you could do it before it's merged, but you certainly should be able to afterwards.

Comment: You were both right, nothing happened. I can't upvote you due to lack of reputation, sorry ;-)